# Benchmarking a KD Tree vs a VP Tree

Tags: machine-learning, cart, k-nearest-neighbour

Hey so I am currently trying to use both a vp tree and a kd tree on a audio dataset, where i have about 10 features and the dataset consists of 1000 samples.
For the KD Tree I use the sklearn package and for the vp tree I am using this one [this one](https://github.com/RickardSjogren/vptree). Now I struggle in how I would actually benchmark these two trees against each other looking at things like how balanced the tree is, crossvalidation, depth of the trees and search times.

Have been trying to look for solutions a couple of days now, any pointers would be greatly appreaciated.